# Contact owner assignment using Round Robin Algorithm

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx

I have a scenario where I have a Custom Object 'Owner Assignment' with fields Owner ID filler with different Users. I want to develop a trigger which will assign the Owner from 'Owner Assignment' object in Round Robin fashion whenever a Contact is created. Can someone help me build the logic for the above scenario since I am new to Salesforce...

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sai i have worked on a similar kind of project a few months back. Here are my findings

I have worked on lead object & assignment rules won't work in our current process. So, i have created a process builder & if an inbound lead meets the criteria I'm calling an invocable apex class from there i have written my logic to dispatch

Note: I have used list custom settings to store whom we assigned the last lead. So, it would be helpful to dispatch records through round-robin fashion.

I have inspired & learned from the below round-robin app by salesforce you can customize the code based on your requirement.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FOmqSUAT

Hope my findings are helpful

Comment: Hi @Pavan tej, Thanks for your quick response. As per my understanding, you have used Process Builder to achieve it. But my requirement is to achieve the same using Trigger. Is it possible using triggers...

Comment: Yes you can but if you look at my answer i have already mentioned I'm calling an apex invocable class from the process.